# AngularJS Tests fail when adding new deps to the module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

So, all tests pass without the 'truncate' module, although the app breaks when I am just serving it with grunt serve without the 'truncate' module.

So tests fail with it, and app breaks without it. What's the deal?

```
angular.module('webClientApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'truncate',
])
```

running the tests with it in the deps list, all the tests fail with undefined errors of the modules I am injecting into the tests:

```
TypeError: httpBackend is undefined in /path/to/test.js
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Most likely the `truncate` module's files are not declared in the `karma.conf.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits goes to Davin in the comment above. I didn't realise that I needed to add them to karma.conf.js as well.